# Examples of Weil's explicit formula

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, mellin-transform

In [**Bombieri**, *PROBLEMS OF THE MILLENNIUM: THE RIEMANN HYPOTHESIS,* **Clay Mathematics Institute** (2000)](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/official_problem_description.pdf), from page 8, **V. Further evidence: the explicit formula** the author tell us that there is a generalization of **Riemann's explicit formula for** $\pi(x)$ the prime-counting function, proved by **Weil**.

In **Explicit Formula** the author tell us what is the formula for a $f\in\mathcal{W}$, see the definition of this class of functions in the article.

> **Question 1.** Can you explain what is the relationship between Weil explicit formula and Riemann explicit formula for the prime-counting function?

To me it is enough the key idea or the specialization if you provide to me a $f\in\mathcal{W}$, or explain the words from the author: that Weil's formula is a generalization of Riemann statement, from a divulgative viewpoint.

> **Question 2.** Please, can you provide us a different example of a specialization of  Weil explicit formula?

Only is required the function $f\in\mathcal{W}$, or hints. But if you want provide a detailed example, as you see, my purpose is understand the theory by means of examples. **Thanks much.**

---

A. **Weil**, *Sur les “formules explicites” de la théorie des nombres premiers,*
Meddelanden Fran Lunds Univ. Mat. Sem. (dedié à M. Riesz), (1952), 252-
265; also, Œuvres Scientifiques–Collected Papers, corrected 2nd printing, SpringerVerlag, New York - Berlin 1980, Vol. II, 48–61

Weil

Comment: Both are exactly the same when you understand that $\zeta(s)$ is just the Laplace transform of the distribution $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta(t-\ln n)$. And because there are those distributions with many Dirac deltas, you need to regularize your formulas. One way is considering $\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n)$ instead of $\Lambda(n)$ (Riemann's explicit formula), the other is using a smooth function $\varphi(x)$ (Weil's explicit formula)

Comment: For understanding all this you need to read : a complex analysis course, a course on the Fourier transform of distributions, and a book on $\zeta(s)$

Comment: You are welcome, @user1952009, very thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question.  I hope others can also give responses.

The key idea behind all the explicit formulas is to use contour integrals of $L$-functions to relate sums over the primes to sums over the zeros.

The Weil and Riemann explicit formulas have similar statements and proofs, but neither is a strict specialization of the other.  Briefly, the Riemann explicit formula is proved by relating a sum over the prime powers
$$\sum_{p^m \leq x} \log p = \sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{(2)} -\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \frac{x^s}{s}\; ds$$
to a contour integral.  Then you move the line of integration all the way to the left to pick up the main term at $s=1$ as well as other terms including the ones over the nontrivial as well as the trivial zeros of the zeta function.

The Weil explicit formula is basically a "smoother" version of Riemann explicit formula, which comes in handy for computations.  Consider a smooth function $\varphi$ with compact support, and let $\hat{\varphi}$ be its Mellin transform.  Then you consider the smoothed sum (rather than a sharp cutoff) and its representation as a contour integral
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \Lambda(n) \varphi(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{(2)} -\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \hat{\varphi}(s)\; ds.$$

There are many different versions of explicit formulas which are all quite similar or even equivalent (e.g. using a Fourier instead of a Mellin transform).  There are also versions for general $L$-functions (see e.g. text by Iwaniec and Kowalski, or text by Moreno).

The Weil explict formula has *many* applications.  For just one example, Poitou and Odlyzko have each used the explicit formula to calculate discriminant lower bounds for number fields.  There are dozens more research papers using the explicit formulas in various ways.

Comment: I'd say you forgot the $n^{-2\sigma}$ term in $\sum_n \Lambda(n) \varphi(n)$

Comment: I don't think I forgot anything.  Just apply Mellin inversion to the integral to see it:  $-(\zeta'/\zeta)(s) = \sum \Lambda(n) n^{-s}$.  Then $(1/2\pi i) \int \hat{\varphi}(s) n^{-s} ds$ is Mellin inversion, and so the $\varphi(n)$ pops out.

Comment: if $\int_{(2)}$ means $\int_{1-i\infty}^{1+i\infty}$ then $-\zeta'/\zeta(1+ix) = \text{FourierT}[\sum_n \frac{\Lambda(n) }{n} \delta(t-\ln n)]$ and $\hat{\varphi}(1+ix) = F[\varphi(t) e^{-t}]$ so that $\frac{-1}{2 i \pi}\int_{1-i\infty}^{1+i\infty} \zeta'/\zeta(s)\hat{\varphi(s)}ds = \langle \varphi(t),\sum_n \frac{\Lambda(n) }{n} \delta(t-\ln n)\rangle = \sum_n \frac{\Lambda(n) }{n^2} \varphi(n)$

Comment: In general, $\int_{(c)}$ is notation for integrating from $c - i\infty$ to $c + i\infty$.  I am using $c=2$ but anywhere in the regional of absolute convergence works.  I'm definitely not integrating over the $1$ line.

Comment: Very thanks much for your answer @JohnM, then I am waiting more responses. Thanks for the clarification about that it isn't posible the specialization from one formula and the other, and he other remarks.

Comment: as an addendum riemann-weil formula is not only for the mangoldt function there is also for mobius, euler phi, divisor and squarefree functions

Answer (score 3):

well there are 'weil-explicit formulae ' for many interesting arithemtic function not only the $ \Lambda $ function

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}g(\log n)=\sum_{\gamma}\frac{h( \gamma)}{\zeta '( \rho )}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\zeta ' (-2n)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dxg(x)e^{-(2n+1/2)x} $$

Also for the Liouville function  we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda(n)}{\sqrt{n}}g(\log n) = \sum_{\gamma}\frac{h( \gamma)\zeta(2 \rho )}{\zeta '( \rho)}+ \frac{1}{\zeta (1/2)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx g(x) $$

For the Euler-Phi function the expicit formula reads

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\varphi(n)}{\sqrt{n}}g(\log n)= \frac{6}{\pi ^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx g(x)e^{3x/2}+ \sum_{\gamma}\frac{h( \gamma)\zeta(\rho/2 )}{\zeta '( \rho)}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta (-2n-1)}{\zeta ' (-2n)}dx g(x) e^{-x(2n+1/2}$$

for the square-free function

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\mu(n)|}{n^{1/4}}g(\log n)=  \frac{6}{\pi ^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx g(x)e^{3x/4}+ \sum_{\gamma}\frac{h( \gamma)\zeta(\rho -1 )}{\zeta '( \rho)}+ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta (-n)}{\zeta ' (-2n)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx g(x)e^{-x(n+1/4)} $$

in all cases the sum is related to the imaginary part of the Riemann zeros $$ \rho = \frac{1}{2}+i \gamma $$ and the test function f and g are related by a Fourier transform $$ g(u)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)\exp (-iux) $$

Comment: Assuming the zeros are simple, and $g$ must have its (bilateral) Laplace transform analytic on the strip containing the zeros, for example if it is compactly supported

Comment: well,  $ g $ or $h$ could also be distribution having a Fourier transform

Comment: This is the case of $g(x) = 1_{x > 0}$ such that the Weil explicit formula is just $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$, but it will converge only in the sense of distribution or analytic continuation

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and attention, I will study in detail your answer, will be very nice examples and a good reference for all us. And also thanks to @user1952009

Comment: http://vixra.org/abs/1310.0048 you have my paper :D to see how i got these conclusions starting page 6

Comment: @JoseGarcia : Just to say be careful it is hard to prove the explicit formula converges, you need to study the [asymptotic distribution of zeros](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_fonction_S.28T.29) and find some $Im(s)$ where $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is small enough such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-1+iT_n}^{2+iT_n} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{x^s}{s}ds =0$, see the last [chapter here](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~koukoulo/documents/notes/primes.pdf)

Comment: Many thanks for the paper, you are generous. I will try to read it.

Comment: can someone search me an endorser so i can publish my findings at arxiv.org ¿¿ or could someone talk to his/her teacher so i can get a grant for my ideas ?

Comment: hi, there where could i contact a teacher to show my work and get a Ph D thesis ?